# В каких случаях NoSQL базы явно лучше Relational Databases?

Tags: база-данных, java, nosql, sql

Вопрос простой.

В каких случаях разработчик должен смотреть на нереляционные базы?

Java, Web.

Comment: а Вы в курсе для чего созданы NoSQL?

Comment: Свежий [пост на хабре][1] в тему. Если возник такой вопрос, то будет полезно почитать.


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/153859/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть мнение, что разработчик должен смотреть на структуру данных, которые он хочет хранить. И потом, исходя из этого, уже выбирать где это будет удобнее хранить. Если все сведется к тому, что данные легко и очевидно ложатся на key-value — вот и случай, когда реляционные БД не будут нужны (будут избыточны). Например, если все что надо держать в БД — текущие прогнозы погоды по городам или сессию со списком-историей последних просмотренных, ходящим по видеохостингу пользователем, клипов, то что-то типа memcached или Redis будет вероятно близко к оптимальному решению.

Обратный подход (есть БД, нужно запихать в нее определенных данные) имеет смысл если речь идет о уже имеющейся инфраструктуре. Там неудобства разработки компенсируются неудобством введения и обслуживания новых элементов (еще одной БД) в уже имеющуюся инфраструктуру.

Comment: Есть одно но по поводу memcached, он не гарантирует вообще сохранности данных. Для хранения всё-таки лучше MemcacheDB.

Comment: Это да. Но, опять же, зависит от того, нужна ли, вообще, сохранность. В списке последних просмотренных клипов, например — вряд ли, данные эфемерные, выкинул и забыл. Потому что хранение и сохранение данных требует свою плату. Вон, в Redis, например, как пришло время сохранения снапшота — так Redis ставит ядерный кэш VFS на дыбы.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю один момент: а какие данные НЕ ложаться на key-value и НЕ подходят для NoSQL? Ведь все можно получить через ключ или range ключей за искл. может специфической статистики.

Comment: @KutaBeach: Не просто ложатся, а «очевидно ложатся.» Это когда смотришь и видишь, что данные имеют такую структуру, что не будет нужно (пере)изобретать велосипеды, и, с непонятными целями, делать из, скажем, Redis'а, этакую недо-MySQL с самописными индексами и реляциями. И, аналогично, не будет иметь смысла брать PostgreSQL и, орудуя блобами и наследованием таблиц, строить из нее этакую документ-ориентированную БД, если окажется достаточным просто взять, скажем, Riak.

Т.е. понятно, что сделать можно все. Все, если на то пошло, в итоге, можно свести к бинарному блобу. Но не все делать нужно.

Comment: Мне понятен пример, когда NoSQL явно лучше: если надо тянуть кучу связанных объектов, что повлечет за собой слишком большое число join-ов. Но не понятно когда NoSQL явно хуже. Вот к примеру: делаем некий планировщик ресурсов. Надо получать список доступных ресурсов на заданную дату или интервал. Вроде как key-value решение подходит, или нет?

Comment: «Голое» key-value (a-la memcached или файловая система) ничего про интервалы не знает. Придется самому все делать, вместо того, чтобы взять более подходящее решение.

Более умное KV, например, Redis или Berkeley DB, умеет. Вот оно и подойдет, если ничего больше не нужно. А если это не просто задачи, а долгоживущие транзакции (которые могут провалиться и все такое), то придется или делать все руками или взять готовое решение «поумнее», что уже реализует требуемое.

Реляционные БД это не какая-то отдельная территория, это просто более навороченные инструменты. Со своими плюсами и минусами этого

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос сложнее, чем кажется. Во-первых дело архитектора смотреть в сторону архитектуры продукта. Во-вторых, не нужно решать проблему раньше, чем она появилась. Единственное исключение тут это графовые БД, которые уместно применять, когда нужно хранить объекты, беспорядочно связанных друг с другом, такие как "друзья" в социальной сети, и при этом абсолютно необходимо регулярно делать по этой структуре неординарный поиск, как, например, регулярный анализ по теории 6ти рукопожатий.

Comment: Хочу добавить, что и MySQL [поддерживает](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/scalabale-persistent-ha-nosql-memcache-storage-using-mysql-cluster/) хранение данных в формате ключ-значение, так и Postgres с помощью [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html). Так что тут вопрос не столько в выборе СУБД, а в выборе того, как вы собираетесь хранить данные. У меня, например, есть опыт хранения реляционных данных в Redis с индексами, занимает всего 300 строк.

Comment: "есть опыт хранения реляционных данных в Redis с индексами", круто, а зачем?

Comment: 1) for fun 2) for profit
Redis всё равно был нужен на проекте для PubSub'а, хранить чисто пользовательские данные в Postgres'е не хотелось, ибо было немного страшно, что умелый пользователь сможет провести иньекцию, а мы предоставляем mongo-подобный API для выборки данных. И городить огород Postgres+Redis+Mongo не хотелось вообще.

Comment: @pirj: Зачем Redis для pubsub'а, когда PostgreSQL умеет в [NOTIFY/LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-notify.html)?

Comment: @drdaeman: Слишком жирно хранить в Postgres'е логи.